# Can't run tsc in package.json

Tags: node.js, typescript

I can't seem to run `tsc` to compile my code using a `package.json` script

```json
    "scripts": {
        "repl": "ts-node \"./src/main.ts\" repl",
        "run": "ts-node \"./src/main.ts\" run",
        "BB": "tsc -p ."
    },
```

This is my `scripts` field running the other two command yield the correct result of my code running but whenever I use `npm run BB` it error:

```
> tsc -p .

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../backend/tsc.js'
```

I do have `typescript` install globally and locally and running `tsc` normally in the terminal yield the `tsc` help list. Running `npm ls -g` give

```
... other packages
+-- prettier@3.0.3
+-- ts-node@10.5.0
+-- typescript@5.3.3
.. other packages
```

and running `npm ls` in the project directory given this

```
+-- @types/node@20.10.5
`-- typescript@5.3.3
```

Comment: What happens when you run `npx tsc`?

Comment: Same error as running it using `npm run`

Comment: then you're going to have to show your ([mcve]) package.json, because if you installed typescript with `npm install typescript`, `npx tcs` should just work. Create an empty dir, `npm init`, then `npm install typescript`, then `npx tsc`. If that works, it's time to start running the MCVE exercise on your "real" dir.

Comment: Uninstall and Reinstall TS seem to work weird that it broke